# Why is /etc/passwd open to public for reading?

Tags: users, etc

Is there any reason that /etc/passwd should be world-wide readable ? It's not like password hashes that shouldn't be exposed, I just want to know why.

Comment: I think when your shell of choice knows to expand `~user` to user's home directory, it's actually looking that up in `/etc/passwd`, so it's nice to have it readable instead of giving all shells elevated rights.

Comment: Expanding "~" is a function of $HOME variable - set $HOME to /var/tmp and then if you do "cd ~" - it will change to /var/tmp.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`/etc/passwd` is sometimes called the user database. That should give us a clue as to why it needs to be readable by everyone. Any utility that inspects file metadata needs to be able to read `/etc/passwd` (and `/etc/group`) in order to be able to resolve the numerical IDs used by the kernel and its subsystems to the human-friendly names that we rely on. Tools that need to find your home directory (mail delivery agents, etc) look that information up in `/etc/passwd`, and `inet` miniservers like `fingerd` look up your details in `/etc/passwd`.

As has been pointed out elsewhere, there is no particularly sensitive data in the file, as modern systems put the password hashes in a shadow password file, which is readable only by root.

Comment: Then, is it for historical reasons it is called `passwd` when in fact this name does not reflect what is in the file?

Comment: Yes, I think so. In very early versions of UNIX, the passwords were indeed stored in `/etc/passwd` (unencrypted at first!). By the time password hashes were moved out to a shadow file, many utilities already existed that relied on other pieces of information in `/etc/passwd`, so the name stuck.

Answer (score 9):

`/etc/passwd` does not contain password hashes (So it is not a big issue). `/etc/shadow` contains password hashes and it is only readable by root (& shadow group)

Comment: On some setups the passwords aren't even in that file because they are in LDAP or some other secured backend!