# /etc/passwd permissions and GECOS field

Tags: permissions, security, users, administration

The default permissions on Ubuntu (or even some BSD) distributions for the `/etc/passwd` file are 644.

It is pointed out in questions like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44854/why-is-etc-passwd-open-to-public-for-reading) that `/etc/passwd` is a sort of user database and it is convenient to make it universally readable.

But this file may also contain (possibly) reserved informations about the users in the [GECOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecos_field) field. Shouldn't these informations be anyway protected?

Or is there another way (newer than GECOS) to store ad secure this kind of data?

Comment: Can you provide an example of "reserved" information in GECOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple newer ways to store this kind of data, including but not limited to LDAP and NIS. The question you have to ask is why there's private information in `/etc/passwd` in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

The personal data in `/etc/passwd` is user names, office locations and phone numbers. That's the 1970s version of the company phonebook. When Unix was designed, it was expected that people who have an account on the same machine would be members of the same organization (colleagues, fellow students, etc.).

If you don't want your users to have access to that kind of information, don't store it in the user database. Users can edit their personal information with the `chfn` command.

If you don't want your users to know anything about other users, including not allowing them to list the user accounts, set up a separate virtual environment for each user.

Answer (score 3):

I would have to agree. `/etc/passwd` has not contained very sensitive data for a while now. I believe `/etc/shadow` is where lots of data that needs to be protected should be stored.

Comment: The shadow file is like the main passwd file, but stores the actual passwords (in a hashed and salted form). I don't know if there's anything else you can hide in shadow - I think all other information in passwd goes into the main file that's readable to all local users.